# How can I put a bounty on other people's questions?

Tags: support, bounty

I know the idea of *Stack Exchange* sites, and the concept of `ranking`.

If I see a question that really interests me, I might put a bounty on it, and if someone answers it to my liking, give them the bounty. This way I benefit and the community benefit. Even the question asker benefits, as the bounty makes more people view the question originally asked.

How can I add bounties to questions asked by others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already do this—provided you and the question meet the [usual bounty criteria](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties)—by clicking the "add a bounty" link at the bottom of the question:

> [image: Bounty link]